# Modify WAMP (or another Open Source LAMP install package) to include another application

Tags: installation, wamp

Is it possible to modify WAMP to install another application besides phpMyAdmin? My app I would need to create a database and setup some configuration files, is this possible to do? Does anyone know of a system that already does this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about adding an application to the popup menu for WAMP?

I have installed Apache James SMTP server for testing sending mail to my localhost. I can then use a POP3 client to read emails that I have been sending from my local testing.

I added a menu option in WAMP for starting James that sits above "phpMyAdmin" on the WAMP popup start menu.

To achieve this I edited c:\wamp\wampmanager.ini and added the following

```
[Menu.Left]
;WAMPMENULEFTSTART
Type: separator; Caption: "Powered by Anaska"
Type: item; Caption: "SMTP James"; Action: run; FileName: "G:/java/smtp-james-2.3.2/bin/run.bat"; Glyph: 5
...
```

You can see the line above with "SMTP James" metioned. It could be any executable file.

Comment: I actually want to modify the installer to include another application (and add to menu)